# Regular expression - Reading until the first encounter of colon (:) and ignoring the rest of the line and the number part in the beginning

Tags: regex

This is the line

```
18. Deutsche Post Brand Value: $3,749 million Headquarter City: Bonn Category: Logistics Year Formed: 1947
```

Desired result is : Deutsche Post Brand Value

With  `.+?(?=:)`, I am getting 18. Deutsche Post Brand Value.

But I don't want 18. in it and rest of the line should be ignored as well

any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use either if supported:

```
^\d+\.\s*\K[^:]+
(?<=^\d+\.\s+)[^:]+
```

See [proof #1](https://regex101.com/r/CJewNn/1) and [proof #2](https://regex101.com/r/CJewNn/3).

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?<=                     look behind to see if there is:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \.                       '.'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-behind
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^:]+                    any character except: ':' (1 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a regex, just split your string on known characters

in this case once at the first `:` after your desired block, then and again at the first space after `18.`

In Python, this could look like

```py
>>> test_string = "18. Deutsche Post Brand Value: $3,749 million Headquarter City: Bonn Category: Logistics Year Formed: 1947"
>>> test_string.split(':')  # show splitting
['18. Deutsche Post Brand Value', ' $3,749 million Headquarter City', ' Bonn Category', ' Logistics Year Formed', ' 1947']
>>>
>>> test_string.split(':')[0].split(' ', 1)[1]
'Deutsche Post Brand Value'
```

---

If you *must* use a regex, you could use a capture group to only match a certain block - example again in Python

```py
>>> import re
>>> re.match(r"\d+\.\s*([^:]+)", test_string).groups()
('Deutsche Post Brand Value',)
```

this works by first matching `\d+` N numbers `\.` literal period `\s*` any number of whitespace chars .. then `()` for a capture group with `[^:]+` match all the values to the next `:`

different regex engines will have some way to refer to this group (often `\1`) or can be directly asked for it (`.groups()` or `.group(1)` for Python)

relevant xkcd:
[image: xkcd 1171]

Answer (score 0):

I used [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/hXCKky/1) to figure out `\d*\. *(.*):` and have the options set to Ungreedy `/U`.
You have to pick your wanted value out of Group 1.

`\d*` means any number of figures
`\.` is a period
  is the space
`(*)` is any characters up to
`:` the colon.